# using par for formatting comments in code with international characters

Tags: comments, code-formatting, par

I'm using Par (in linux) to get nice comments formatting quickly. The problem is that now I want to introduce comments that include some international characters, like áéíóú or äëïöü...

The program Berkeley Par considers these international characters as 2 ASCII characters (I believe) and it outputs the comments somehow broken because it doesn't count characters properly.

Did you face this problem before? Do you have any solution? Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the code from [Add multibyte characters support in "par"](http://sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?2006/06/22/55-add-multibyte-characters-support-in-par) (or just the patches applied to the original source) don't work for you?

Then maybe it is a problem with your shell or the font it uses. Are you sure the shell and font you use is able to reproduce unicode characters

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!! This works. Is not the same as distributed in Gentoo Linux nor the one you can find in the original web page.

Answer (score 1):

I've never even heard of this tool, but check out [par 1.52](http://www.nicemice.net/par/).

> The latest version of Par, released on 2001-Apr-29, tar'd and gzip'd. The only real change is better support for 8-bit character sets (as opposed to just 7-bit ASCII), but see also the [release notes](http://www.nicemice.net/par/releasenotes.var).

**Edit**: On the page, see [par_1.52-i18n.3.diff.gz](http://www.nicemice.net/par/par_1.52-i18n.3.diff.gz):

> A patch by Jérôme Pouiller that adds
>   support for multibyte charsets (like
>   UTF-8), plus Debian packaging. Copied
>   from http://sysmic.org/par/debian/.
>   See also his [original announcement](http://sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?2006/06/22/55-add-multibyte-characters-support-in-par).

Comment: This program is the same one I'm using, including version number. I don't know why sometimes is known as Berkley Par :)
However, is not supporting it. Maybe is a gentoo linux problem building it? :S

Comment: Actually compiling this version doesn't work right with the UTF-8 characters either...

Answer (score 1):

Par, as distributed in Ubuntu from Hardy on, is supposed to handle multi-byte encodings.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/par